# Spring 4.x Java code-based configuration: Static resource files and Dispatcher servlet

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets

Prior to servlet version 3.0, all configuration are xml based.
I'm currently using code/annotation based configuration.

In xml style configuration, we have

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/res/**" location="/res/" />
```

How can I translate it into code based configuration? I keep receiving error from eclipse debug console that there is no dispatcher servlet found for resource file.

BTW, here is my reference, [Migrating from Spring Security 3.x to 4.x (Java Configuration)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-jc.html)

**initializer**

```
public class AppInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { SecurityConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { MvcConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

**mvc config**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({ "com.appname.controller" })
public class MvcConfig {
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

**security config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password")
                .roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/res/**").permitAll()
            .and().authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/account/signin").permitAll()
            .and().logout().permitAll();
    }
}
```

**security initializer**

```
public class SecurityInitializer extends
        AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

**custom login**

```
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    public CustomUserDetailsService() {
        this.accountRepository = new AccountRepository();
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        Account account = accountRepository.getAccountByEmail(email);

        if (account == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid email/password.");
        }

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));

        return new User(account.getEmail(), account.getPassword(), authorities);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend from [`WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html) and override the [`addResourceHandlers`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html#addResourceHandlers-org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry-) method

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"com.appname.controller"})
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/res/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/res/");
    }
}
```