# Spring Security - j_spring_security_check - HTTP status 403

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Im the new at Spring Security. 
If I press log in, the site: http://localhost:8080/j_spring_security_check occurs with

```
HTTP Status 403 – Forbidden
Type Status Report

Message Forbidden

Description The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.12
```

Here is **web.xml**

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/webcontext/security-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/webcontext/DispatcherServlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

login.jsp
```

And here:  `<form action="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check"></c:url>" method="post">` -  `/j_spring_security_check` is marked on the red with the error: `Cannot resolve controller URL '/j_spring_security_check'`

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Produkty</title>
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Produkty</h1>
            <p>Dodaj produkty</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Zaloguj się</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <c:if test="${not empty error}">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <spring:message code="AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials"/><br/>
                    </div>
                    </c:if>
                    <form action="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check"></c:url>" method="post">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Nazwa użytkownika" name='j_username' type="text">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Hasło" name='j_password' type="password" value="">
                            </div>
                            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Zaloguj się">
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**security-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd">
    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/products/add" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/products/add"
                             authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed"/>
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout"/>
    </security:http>
    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="Admin" password="Admin123" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

What should I add to make it right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring security 4 custom login j\_spring\_security\_check return http 302](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29554850/spring-security-4-custom-login-j-spring-security-check-return-http-302)

Answer (score 5):

check csrf token

if you use form tag with post url you should send with **token parameter**

```
<form>
  <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}"/>
</form>
```

or

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
http
    .csrf().disable()
```

url should be allowed in security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
http
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/j_spring_security_check").permitAll()
```

Comment: where should i place form tag? in `security-context.xml`?

Comment: in <form action="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check"></c:url>" method="post"> tag <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>

Answer (score 2):

Its because request does not contain `csrf` token, since spring security automatically enables it, `csrf` token must be sent with request. It is not a good idea to simply disable this, which leaves entire application wide open.

Add following hidden input to your form,

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

If you want to disable `csrf` support, use this in `security-context.xml`. (Spring 4+)

```
<http>
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
</http>
```

Comment: which one is better?

Comment: @pipilam  i'd use csrf token, but that depends

Comment: @pipilam you need to paste this `<input>` in html `<form>`

Comment: and now I've got another error, that `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/j_spring_security_check] in DispatcherServlet with name 'DefaultServlet'`. Everything should works right...

Comment: @pipilam try /login instead

Comment: Yeah, but this is not it. If I want to add product, I got localhost..../login and when I press "log in" `localhost...//j_spring_security_check` appears and there is error.